# An error while loading shared libraries

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, libraries

I was trying to run a program called "**solvate**" and I found a following error. Kindly let me know how do I solve this problem. I am using "ubuntu 14.04", 64 bit
Thank you in advance!

With regards,
Jana

> **Error message:**
>
> ./solvate: error while loading shared libraries:
> libboost_program_options-mt.so.1.38.0: cannot open shared object file:
> No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

> `./solvate: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_program_options-mt.so.1.38.0`

This error means that the executable `solvate` could not find one of the Boost libraries that it requires. There are several common causes:

1. the library is not present on the system at all, or
2. the library is present, but not in a location that runtime linker searches, or
3. the library is present, but for the *wrong architecture*

> `locate  libboost_program_options-mt.so.1.38.0`
>    `/usr/lib/libboost_program_options-mt.so.1.38.0`

This output tells us that neither 1, nor 2 are likely. Therefore cause 3 must be it.

On a 64-bit Ubuntu, `/usr/lib` is where 64-bit libraries are installed. You can verify that `/usr/lib/libboost_program_options-mt.so.1.38.0` is a 64-bit library with:

```
file /usr/lib/libboost_program_options-mt.so.1.38.0
```

which should print:

```
/usr/lib/libboost_program_options-mt.so.1.38.0: ELF 64-bit LSB  shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked ...
```

It *must* also be true that `./solvate` is a *32-bit* executable. You can confirm that with

```
file ./solvate
```

which should print

```
./solvate: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), ...
```

Finally, to solve your problem:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev:i386
```